# /dev/sdc should be checked for errors

Tags: fsck

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this? I tried looking online but for some reason not a lot is coming up, as if it's a big secret or something.

Every time I connect to it I see "**/dev/sdc should be checked for errors**" and below that (not sure if this is related) it says ***** System restart required *****

I did not set this server up but what I do know is /dev/sdc is an iSCSI connection to a RAID volume on a Promise VessRAID 1840i.

Are there ways to test the volume w/out unmounting the filesystem or effecting user's access to the data on it? If so please explain what needs to be done.

Thanks!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14928/how-to-check-a-mounted-filesystem-for-errors-in-a-reliable-way?rq=1

Comment: That sounds like it's coming from fsck so you should probably unmount it and check it out. **tune2fs** is your friend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check a mounted filesystem for errors in a reliable way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14928/how-to-check-a-mounted-filesystem-for-errors-in-a-reliable-way)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to unmount the drive to check the file system for errors. You can't do it while the filesystem is live.

- Ensure `FSCKFIX=yes` is present in `/etc/default/rcS` (it's `no` by default).
- Run `touch /forcefsck`, and reboot the system.
- Revert your changes to `rcS` once fsck is complete.

Comment: if the filesystem that should be checked is not the root filesystem then also set the fsck order in /etc/fstab 2 for all the partitions that aren't the root filesystem that you want to be checked.