# Persistent "disk will be checked..." in the message of the day (motd) even after reboot

Tags: hard-drive, fsck, motd

I see that there are some other threads that mention this error, but I have tried the solutions with no luck.

When I log into my 12.04 Server, I get the message:

```
/dev/sdb1 will be checked for errors at next reboot
/dev/sdc1 will be checked for errors at next reboot
```

The problem is that the check is never done and I continue to get the messages.  I ran a fsck on both drives and they are fine.

Comment: I just rebooted again and didn't get the warning...

Comment: I tried a suggestion to do `touch /forcefsck` and reboot, but I'm still getting this warning.

Comment: See if this helps you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/60249/why-does-ubuntu-ask-to-check-my-hard-drives-every-so-often

Comment: The message in the message of the day (motd) about drives being checked doesn't go away even when the drives *have* been checked. This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/692355) in Ubuntu. This is caused because that message is cached in the file `/var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot` so that it is not constantly recomputed. `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot` checks the timestamp on the file and is supposed to regenerate it every so often. However, there is a bug and the timestamp gets set in such a way that it never regenerate

Comment: I have a similar warning on Ubuntu 14.04.1:  *** /dev/xvda1 should be checked for errors ***  No bad blocks. Log shows everything OK. Is this the same bug?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/692355) in Ubuntu 11.04 and apparently [still exists in 12.04 LTS](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/692355/comments/8). What happens is what you described: you keep getting the notification even though there is nothing wrong with your hard drive and no checks are scheduled/will be done.

[It's caused by](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/692355/comments/9) the `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot` script generating a `/var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot` file with a timestamp in the future. The previous link has a convoluted solution from one of the Ubuntu maintainers (Steve Langasek), but it may be simplest [to just do this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/692355/comments/13):

1. Open a terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T`
2. Type:

   ```
   sudo rm /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot
   ```
3. Exit the terminal and reboot (or logout/login).

Comment: In my case editing the file and removing the text resolved the problem. When I tried removed it at next login it would simply recreate the file so it the problem would persist.

Comment: Here a command that will fix the problem without any sort of reboot or logout: `sudo bash -c 'rm /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot && for file in /etc/update-motd.d/*; do $file; done > /var/run/motd' && cat /etc/motd`

Comment: Still a problem on 14.04 but this solution didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 11):

```
cat /dev/null > /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot
```

Fixed this for me....

Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.

```
3.2.0-51-generic #77-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 24 20:18:19 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Yeah, when I did `rm fsck-at-reboot`, it was recreated when I logged in again. So I had to edit `fsck-at-reboot` to delete the message. (This was for an AWS EC2 Ubuntu 13 machine)

Comment: Same here, editing it instead of removing resolved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem today - turned out in my /etc/fstab file, the line that had the relevant filesystem, had "0" in the last field, which means don't fsck it on boot. This should have been "1" for the root filesystem, or "2" for any other filesystem.

Also, my `motd` wasn't updated after the (successful) fsck. You can use this command:

```
tune2fs -l /dev/something
```

Then look for a line that says "Last Checked".

Comment: This is quite helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to change `fstab`. I think this is managed elsewhere.