# Keep getting checked for errors message when logging in at command line

Tags: 12.04, fsck

I am running 12.04 LTS completely update.

When logging in on the command line, I see this message

```
*** /dev/sda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
```

I've rebooted once and got the message upon logging in on the command line; then used the sudo touch /forcefsdk command and rebooted; and I still get this message.

How can I clear the message, and does it really make a difference?

If it helps this system shutdown uncleanly due to a power failure, but has rebooted and acted fine since.

**cat /etc/fstab**

```
 ics@steamboy:~$ cat /etc/fstab
    # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
    #
    # Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
    # for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
    # devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
    #
    # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
    proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
    # / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
    UUID=a15471c6-56f1-419f-89fa-73a5f3c7253e /    ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
    /dev/sdb1 /media/xtra    ext3 errors=remount-ro 0 1

    # swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
    UUID=a544f2c5-6e09-44ec-8130-a524a12a99c0 none        swap    sw              0       0
    /dev/sdc0       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
    ics@steamboy:~$
```

**cat .bashrc**

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything [ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1) HISTSIZE=1000 HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS. shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1) [ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below) if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
     debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot) fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color) case "$TERM" in
     xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;; esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

 if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
     if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then  # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48     #
 (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such  # a
 case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)    color_prompt=yes
     else   color_prompt=
     fi fi

 if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
     PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
 ' else
     PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ ' fi unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

 # If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir case "$TERM" in xterm*|rxvt*)
     PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
     ;;
 *)
     ;; esac

 # enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
     test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
     alias ls='ls --color=auto'
     #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
     #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

     alias grep='grep --color=auto'
     alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
     alias egrep='egrep --color=auto' fi

 # some more ls aliases alias ll='ls -alF' alias la='ls -A' alias l='ls -CF'

 # Alias definitions.
 # You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
 # ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
 # See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

 if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
     . ~/.bash_aliases fi

 # enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
 # this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
 # sources /etc/bash.bashrc). if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
     . /etc/bash_completion fi

 unset USERNAME

 export CVSROOT=:ext:cvsuser@revision_control:/home/cvsuser/SRC_TREE
 export CVS_RSH=ssh

 export TERM=vt100

 if [ "`tty`" != "not a tty" ]; then    stty clocal     stty erase      stty
 echoe fi

 export TERMCAP=/etc/termcap.RHEL3 export EDITOR=vim

 export
 PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/python-django/bin:~/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/home/amr/bin:$PATH
 export PYTHONPATH=/home/cnorton/bin:/home/amr/bin:$PYTHONPATH

 export PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp/cnorton/.python-eggs export
 CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java:/home/cnorton/bin:$CLASSPATH

 export
 VIMCLOJURE_SERVER_JAR="$HOME/bin/server-2.3.0-20101203.173832-1.jar"
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the results of `cat /etc/fstab` & `cat .bashrc`

Comment: Could not get .bashrc to format correctly. Sorry.

Comment: I just rebooted again; could not get a boot menu by pressing either SHIFT or ESC, but the message is now gone.

Comment: You have to hold the SHIFT down. Not just pressing (one or two times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if your .bashrc file creates this problem , as is not the Official.

The standard .bashrc file ends here

```
. /etc/bash_completion fi
```

All bellow are either your additions of some program's additions.

As for the fstab , seems good. The only "mistake" I can see is the fsck.order in `/dev/sdb1`

Fsck order has to be 1 only for root partition. Any other partitions should have 2 .

So the correct line for /dev/sdb1 is

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/xtra    ext3 errors=remount-ro 0 2
```

Correct this and see if your problem solved.

Also read here a good tutorial on [How-to Fstab](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=283131)

---

Linked Q&A:

- [Persistent "disk will be checked..." in the message of the day (motd) even after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163184/repeated-disk-will-be-checked-messages-when-logging-into-cli-server/283509?noredirect=1#163184)