# Why aren't my drives fscking

Tags: ext4, fsck, motd

I logged on to my Ubuntu server and the message of the day contained these wonderful messages:

```
*** /dev/sda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
*** /dev/sda6 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
```

Now, I loves me some healthy file systems so I reboot after doing my thing, but when I next log in, the same messages appear. Sure enough, `dumpe2fs` dutifully informs me that the last check is still way way in the past and the next check date, while not being as far, is not in the future.

Now, I made sure the system checked everything with a pair of forcefsck files and that got rid of the messages, but I still don't understand what could cause my server not to run a file system check despite telling me it needs to do one.

Comment: @geezanansa: A forcefsck file at the root of each drive. /forcefsck and /home/forcefsck. When I say the forcefsck got rid of the message, I mean manually fscking did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because the message is stuck in motd.  See the answer on: [Persistent "disk will be checked..." in the message of the day (motd) even after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163184/repeated-disk-will-be-checked-messages-when-logging-into-cli-server/283509)

The solution:  remove the file `/var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot` and reboot, or run this command line to remove the file and fully regenerate the message of the day:

```
sudo bash -c 'rm /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot && for file in /etc/update-motd.d/*; do $file; done > /var/run/motd' && cat /etc/motd
```