# How to analyze and defragment drive in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, fsck, defrag

I want to check whether my root drive requires a defragmentation. If requried I am planning to do this `sudo e4defrag -c /dev/<my partition>` I followed [this method](https://askubuntu.com/a/861593/158636) to analyze my disk.

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/<my partition>
```

Then I rebooted my system but its showing nothing on my reboot and directly goes to the login page. How to analyze and defrag a drive in ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Have you considered downloading Bleachbit from the Ubuntu Software Centre?

Comment: I did this `sudo bleachbit -c --preset` for clearing my system. But it  exits after sometime with a error `filesystem root has 99 MB left`. Tried unchecking some options and rerun bleachbit but the problem still exists. Thats why I am not going to go bleachbit way

Comment: I suggest that you try to repair the root file system. Boot from another drive, for example an Ubuntu install drive (USB or DVD) and run an `e2fsck` command according to [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986). Scroll down to 'Repair linux file systems with linux tools'.

Comment: Looks like the problem is your partition is full . Significant fragmentation is very rare in linux

Comment: `sudo fsck.ext2 -fn /dev/sdXY` will show fragmentation. The problem probably is your partition is full

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ubuntu doesn't need disk-defragmenting

From this [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/115229/htg-explains-why-linux-doesnt-need-defragmenting/):

> If you’re a Linux user, you’ve probably heard that you don’t need to
> defragment your Linux file systems. You’ll also notice that Linux
> distributions don’t come with disk-defragmenting utilities. But why is
> that?
>
> To understand why Linux file systems don’t need defragmenting in
> normal use – and Windows ones do – you’ll need to understand why
> fragmentation occurs and how Linux and Windows file systems work
> differently from each other.

Comment: Although very rare one can see significant fragmentation in Linux. This happens when the partition is full and the op suggests this may be the case

Comment: So, the answer (from the article) in case your drive is full and fragmented is: Free up some space (delete some files), copy remaining files to a new drive, erase the old drive, then copy the files back to the old drive. Voila! Fragmentation gone. Seems like there is room for improvement there.