# Non-Snap Installed Applications Stop Randomly

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, shutdown, error-handling

hoping the community can help me with this one.

I have a Razer 2020 Base edition that I've installed Ubuntu into recently.  Here are my system details from running `hostnamectl`:

```
Static hostname: xxx-Blade-15-Base-Model-Early-2020-RZ09-0328
Icon name: computer-laptop
Chassis: laptop
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-48-generic
Architecture: x86-64
```

I've run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` recently to ensure it isn't some sort of issue stemming from being out of date.

What's happening is that any application that I haven't installed with snap will lose its icon and cease to function, either closing or giving errors like 'Can't find Wi-Fi' in the case of browsers.  Further, when I suspend the computer and try to log in again, I'm unable to and get a message saying Authentication Denied.  The only way to solve this is to perform a hard restart on my computer, since when I just try a simple power off I get a never-ending list of messages saying that the system can't write logs. In particular the message alternates between different flavours of these two:

```
systemd-journald[331]: Failed to write entry (22 items, 779/790 Bytes), ignoring: Read-Only file system
EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p6): __ext4_find_entry:1531: inode #9830844/9830555: comm gmain: reading directory iblock 0
```

This happens without warning, and there's nothing I've come across so far that triggers it to happen.  I'll just suddenly see some applications lose their icons in the activities bar, then finally the toolbar, and everything will then stop working.  Previously this was a rare occurrence, but it seems to be becoming more frequent.

Could it have something to do with my dual boot configuration?  My applications manager?  What steps should I take to troubleshoot this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force fsck.ext4 on reboot, but really "forceful"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14740/force-fsck-ext4-on-reboot-but-really-forceful)

Comment: @N0rbert Are you suggesting to force performing an fsck on the next boot because of the `EXT4-fs error` error message?

Comment: @karel, yes, right. I suppose that FS is not clean. Using livecd may be an option too.

Comment: @N0rbert @karel 
I've run `fsck` on nvme0n1p6 while using a USB boot of Ubuntu and it has come back with no errors whatsoever.  What should I try next?